# Cloud functions email using Nodemailer is sending half the time

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

I have a firebase cloud function that triggers once a user sends a form. That function is supposed to send me an email. The function triggered and executed in cloud logging but i didn't get the email. To be fair, sometimes i get an email, sometimes I don't.

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: ...,
  port: ...,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: process.env.REACT_OUTGOING_EMAIL,
    pass: process.env.REACT_EMAIL_PASSWORD,
  },
});

exports.bookingCreationEmail = functions
  .runWith({
    timeoutSeconds: 120
  })
  .firestore.document(`bookings/{booking}`)
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    try {
      const mailOptions = {
        from: ` "Admin" ${process.env.REACT_OUTGOING_EMAIL}`,
        to: `${process.env.REACT_OUTGOING_EMAIL}`,
        subject: `New Form Submitted`,
        html: `<h1>New Form Submitted</h1>`,
      };

      await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
      console.log("Booking Creation Sent!");
      return null;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error from sending mail: ", error);
      return null;
    }
  });
```

Below is the results from logging:
[image]

In this instance, i didn't get an email. What is wrong with my cloud function?

Comment: There are many reasons that you, or your client, will fail to receive an email. SPAM filters have their own rules to determine "spamminess". Do you have the correct DNS SPF, DMARC, and DKIM resource records? Some mail servers will evaluate your email content for "spamminess". None of those issues are related to the Google Cloud service you are using. The magic is to configure your mail servers, DNS servers, and mail content to minimize being flagged as SPAM.